# awk check for fields in CSV file smeeting certain criteria

Tags: awk, sh

I'm trying to write a simple file sanity check script. I have a directory with dozen CSV files containing **id,edname,firstname,lastname,suffix,email**.

I like to write a awk script to check if first field contain a number and is not empty. and fields number 3,4 & 6 are not empty and that the file contains 6 fields no more no less than 6, if all of this conditions are true nothing happens but if any of these conditions failed, re-name the file to `.bad`. Here is what i have done so far.

```
for f in *.csv; do 
    awk -F, '{ exit (NF ==6 ? 0:1) }' "$f" && echo mv "$f" "${f}.bad"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual answer, you find e.g. in [6.3.2.2 Comparison Operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Comparison-Operators.html) of the GNU Awk online doc.:

You can use

> x != y    True if x is not equal to y

to compare if a field is not empty.

You can use

> x ~ y True if the string x matches the regexp denoted by y

to check whether it matches a certain pattern.

Your awk script extended respectively:

```
{ exit (NF==6 && $1~/[1-9][0-9]*/ && $3!="" && $4!="" && $6!="") ? 0 : 1 }
```

A small demonstration:

```
$ cat >good.txt <<'EOF'
1,edname,firstname,lastname,suffix,email
2,edname,firstname,lastname,suffix,email
EOF

$ cat >bad_nr_fields.txt <<'EOF'
> 1,edname,firstname,lastname,suffix
> EOF

$ cat >bad_id.txt <<'EOF'
> A,edname,firstname,lastname,suffix,email
> EOF

$ cat >bad_firstname.txt << 'EOF'
> 1,edname,,lastname,suffix,email
> EOF

$ for FILE in good.txt bad_nr_fields.txt bad_id.txt bad_firstname.txt; do
>   echo $FILE":"
>   if awk -F, '{ exit (NF==6 && $1~/[1-9][0-9]*/ && $3!="" && $4!="" && $6!="") ? 0 : 1 }' "$FILE"; then echo "good"
>   else echo "bad"
>   fi
> done
good.txt:
good
bad_nr_fields.txt:
bad
bad_id.txt:
bad
bad_firstname.txt:
bad

$
```

Of course, I don't know which specific syntax your number for `id` has to match. In my case, I used the pattern for decimal integers which may not start with '0'. (This excludes number '0' as well.)